# I'm trying to write a three conditional statement

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Hello I have this line right now with an if else statement and I'm trying to convert it to if else if else statement.

This is coffescript

```
_index = if $product.find('.dot.active').index() then 0 else 1
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the else if?  makes it hard to help construct when we don't know the logic.  You may be able to utilize a switch statement or a ternary expression.  But if I could see the other condition, we may be able to give you other options.

Comment: Basically I have a slider with 3 images and doing an if else if else to see which of them have the active slide and Removing / Adding a class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_index = if $product.find('.dot.active').index() then 0 else if 1 then 2 else 3
```

I think this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

```
_index = if $product.find('.dot.active').index() 
   then 0 
else 
   if <some other condition> then <some other result> else <yet another result>
```

Comment: You only need the `then`s in the single-line form, the [multi-line form](http://coffeescript.org/#try:a%20%3D%20if%20one%0A%20%20%20%20%20%201%0A%20%20%20%20else%20if%20two%0A%20%20%20%20%20%202%0A%20%20%20%20else%0A%20%20%20%20%20%203%0A) would normally be written like any other if/else if/else block.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, an alternative to using **if** that achieves the same thing, arguably clearer, would be to use the **switch** statement like this:

```
_index = switch $product.find('.dot.active').index() 
  when false then 0 
  when 1 then 2 
  else 3
```